# My pi with berryboot with vnc enabled wont work

Tags: boot-issues, bootloader, berryboot

In Berryboot's `cmdline.txt`, I added

```
vncinstall ipv4=192.168.2.16/255.255.255.0/192.168.2.1
```

and my ipconfig for my xp computer is:

```
Windows IP Configuration


Ethernet adapter Wireless Network Connection:

        Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : home
        IP Address. . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.2.20
        Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
        Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.2.1

Ethernet adapter Network Connect Adapter:

        Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
```

but berryboot says connect with vnc now, but when i connect, it goes to emergency shell

Answer (score 1):

The VNC client you are using must request 24-bit color (*not* 256 colors palleted mode). TightVNC and krdc work fine by default, for RealVNC make sure you enable FullColour in the settings

Answer (score 0):

Make sure, `cmdline.txt` contains everything in **single line** only, example:

```
smsc95xx.turbo_mode=N elevator=deadline quiet bootmenutimeout=60 vncinstall ipv4=192.168.88.88/255.255.255.0/192.168.88.1/wlan0
```

Answer (score 0):

vnc workwd for me but it only works when no os is installed for installing os. once you install the os and boot into that your vnc will not work because it is configured for berryboot manager and not for your os you boot into.